# how to get list of materialize css chips element in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, materialize, angularjs-ng-model

```
<div ng-repeat="job in jobList" >
    <div class="chip" id="jobchip" ng-model="jobchip">
        <label for="jobchip"> Jobs</label>
        {{job.Name}}
        <i class="close material-icons">close</i>
    </div>
 </div>
```

AngularCode

```
$scope.jobList=["it","hr","crm"];
console.log($scope.jobchip);
```

how do i get the list of selected chips in the ng-model jobchip i have tried to access it through $scope variable the console output returns undefined

Comment: did you did this using angular material

Answer (score 0):

Angular has `angular.element()` to get elements by class or id

you can use

```
var elems = angular.element('.chip');
console.log(elems);
```

to get array of element those has chip class

example:

html

```
<div id="hello" class="whatever">1</div>
<div id="hey" class="whatever">2</div>
<div id="haha" class="whatever">3</div>
<div class="whatever">4</div>
```

controller

```
var elems = angular.element('.whatever');
console.log(elems);
elems = angular.element('#hello');
console.log(elems);
```

in console

```
[div#hello.whatever, div#hey.whatever, div#haha.whatever, div.whatever, prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".whatever"]
[div#hello.whatever, context: document, selector: "#hello"]
```

you can expand the log in console and get

```
n.fn.init[4]
  0: div#hello.whatever
  1: div#hey.whatever
  2: div#haha.whatever
  3: div.whatever
n.fn.init[1]
  0: div#hello.whatever
```

Hope it helps